# Binding Linq.EntityRef to Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a linq object created from a table called ds_User.  ds_User has a foreign key to a table called ds_NetworkGroup on ds_User.GroupID = ds_NetworkGroup.GroupID.  When I populate a generic list of ds_User, I get the ds_NetworkGroup associated with each entry through System.Data.Linq.EntityRef.  I am now binding my ds_User to a gridview by explicitly creating each column.  However, I want to display ds_NetworkGroup.Name instead of ds_User.GroupID.  I tried DataField="ds_NetworkGroup.Name" but that errors.  Is there a way to do this?

```
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="UsersGV" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None" 
        OnRowEditing="UsersGV_RowEditing"
        OnRowCancelingEdit="UsersGV_CancelEdit"
        OnRowUpdating="UsersGV_Updating"
        OnRowDeleting="UsersGV_Deleting" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        >
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="GroupId" HeaderText="GroupId" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="UserID" />
            <asp:DynamicField DataField="ds_NetworkGroup.Name" HeaderText="GroupName" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>


    public List<ds_User> GetAllUsers()
    {
        List<ds_User> allUsers = DC1.ds_Users.ToList();
        return allUsers;
    }


    private void BindGrid()
    {
        UserClass myUsers = new UserClass();

        List<ds_User> users = new List<ds_User>();
        users = myUsers.GetAllUsers();

        if (users.Count > 0)
        {
            UsersGV.DataSource = users;
            UsersGV.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I think you need to put EF's table, clases and some code to help you. Without that we can't help you.

Comment: I need to put some Entity Framework's table, classes and some code?  Is that what you're saying?  I'm not sure I know what to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="GroupName" SortExpression="GroupName">
        <ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="lblGroupName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ds_NetworkGroups.Name")%>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Pretty simple...just took a little trial and error.